# Moving MongoDB to Multikeys but indexOnly is returning false

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongojs, multikey

What I'm trying to do sounds logical to me however I'm not sure.

I am trying to improve part of a MongoDB collection by using Multikeys.

For example: I have multiple documents with the following format:

**Document:**

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("528a4177dbcfd00000000013"),
   "name": "Shopping",
   "tags": [
     "retail",
     "shop",
     "shopping",
     "store",
     "grocery" 
  ] 
}
```

**Query:**
Up until now, I have been using the following query to match the `tags` field.

```
var tags = Array("store", "shopping", "etc");
db.collection.findOne({ 'tags': { $in: tags } }, { name: true });
```

This has been working well, however I think Multikeys should be used in this instance to improve speed & performance. Please, correct me if I am wrong!

**Indexing:**
I issued the following command in an attempt to index the `tags`.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { tags: 1 }, { safe: true }, function(err, doc) {} );
```

`ensureIndex` was successful.

**Result:**
However when using RockMongo's `explain` feature on the above query, the result is:

```
{
   "indexOnly": false,
   "indexBounds": {
     "tags": [
       [
         "etc",
         "etc" 
      ],
       [
         "shopping",
         "shopping" 
      ],
       [
         "store",
         "store" 
      ] 
    ] 
  }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Why is indexing not working, is there something else I have to do?
2. Is Multikey indexing in this case beneficial? (*I'm assuming yes.*)
3. Is there another form of indexing that would be more beneficial?

**Edit:**
I've just noticed that in the RockMongo `explain` data there is a field:
`"isMultiKey": true,`
could it be that Multikeys are being used and I've completely misunderstood that it IS being indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in your edit, and coming from the part of explain you did not post is that `isMulyiKey: true` along with other information on the cursor are showing that the index is being used. The `indexBounds` are another indicator.

What is being described by [indexOnly](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.indexOnly) is the fact that your query contains another field, `name`, which is not part of the index. When the query optimizer sees that all elements of the query can be met by using the fields from *within the index* this is referred to as a [covered query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#indexes-covered-queries) and the `indexOnly` property here is set to true.

So in an *Ideal* situation your query and results are using the information from the *index only* and MongoDB does not *also* have to look up the entry from the index in the collection in order to return more data.